# Триггер через определённое нажатие

Tags: unity3d

Делаю Clicker. Мне нужно чтобы через каждое определённое количество нажатий появлялась реклама. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Это немного грубый вариант. Я бы посоветовал проверять где кликнул  пользователь. А это можете сделать с помощью [IPointerEnterHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) или [IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html)

```cs
int clickCount;

private void Update()
{
   if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
   {
       clickCount++;
   }

   if(clickCount % 100 == 0)
   {
       //Тут вам нужно активировать рекламу
       clickCount = 0;
   }
}
```